# web services throwing errors intermittently

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a web service running on server but once in a while it throws an error. This is happening when calling one particular method and all other method works fine but on calling this method I receive following error:-

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   https://xxx/xxx/xxx.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint
>   binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP
>   request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the
>   service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Currently it happened after running fine for 2 weeks. Strangely the method started working fine again after few hours. I am wondering where should I start looking to troubleshoot this issue? Any pointers to troubleshoot shall be helpful.

Just to add to this today I received below error:-

> The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected
>   to be kept alive was closed by the server

Can both of the error be related to each other?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share the service operation and internal implementation please

Comment: Is your service behind a load balancer?

Comment: @Kye No there is no load balancer that service needs to bypass. Thank you!

Comment: Is the service running in a transaction? Could there be additional load on the service causing the transaction to timeout and rollback?

Comment: @TomRedfern Sorry for delay in response. The method is quite complex and long to be posted here. It basically communicates with other services and returns the records updated after time passed as parameter. I understand that it might be an issue with the code and if that is really the case I want to know where should I look for. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you hosted in IIS or windows service?

Comment: @TomRedfern Hosted in IIS on windows server 2012

Comment: i updated the post with some additional error message received today.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered that error.
I encountered that error when almost thousands of user simultaneously accessing the web service.

I put this piece of code..

```
 ServiceClient = new ServiceClient ();

 var customBinding = new CustomBinding(ServiceClient.Endpoint.Binding);
 var transportElement = customBinding.Elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>();
 transportElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;

 ServiceClient.Endpoint.Binding = customBinding;
 ServiceClient.Open();
```

Comment: Thanks will try out that. Can there be any implications of using that property?